# Set Column as HyperLink in AutoGenerated GridView

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have auto generated grid view, it is generated as:

```
gvOffer.DataSource = offer.View(ddlResult.SelectedValue);
gvOffer.DataBind();
```

I need to set the first and second column as hyperlink. In other words, the rows under 1st and 2nd column has to be in hyperlink state. What should i do? Most answers i found request me to set auto-generated to false which i try to avoid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the DataFormatString to be in the form of a URL as shown here:  http://forums.asp.net/p/1127741/1780013.aspx

slightly modified - you'll need to set the formatstring in code-behind just before doing the DataBind() call. (code untested, sorry I'm not at my Dev PC)

```
gvoffer.Columns[0].DataFormatString = "<a href=\"http://mywebsite/page.aspx?q={0}\">{0}</a>"
gvoffer.Columns[0].HtmlEncode = false;
```

Be sure to set the HtmlEncode property of the column to "false" or the url will just be htmlencoded and useless (although I see in the link below that this only applies to .NET 3.0 and earlier.)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            string value = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
            e.Row.Cells[0].Text = Convert.ToString("<a href=\"Office.aspx?number=" + value + "\">" + value + "</a>"); 
        }
    }
```